# .show() not working after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Okay, so I am trying to initially hide a table when a user navigates to my page and then when a form is submitted, I process it with Ajax and display the results table.

However, when I run the code it is refreshing to page and defaulting to the display none setting.

here is my css and javascript:

js:

```
   <script> 

      var frm = $('#myform');
      frm.submit(function () {
          $('#loader').show();
          $('#results-table').hide();
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
              type: frm.attr('method'),
              url: frm.attr('action'),
              data: frm.serialize(),
              async: true,
              success: function (data) {
                  $('#loader').hide();
                  $('#results-table').show();
                  $("#results-table").html(data);
              },

          });
          return false;

      });

    </script>
```

css:

```
      #results-table {
        display: none;

      }
```

html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-responsive" id="results-table" >

<form action="{% url 'results-view' %}" method="POST" class="autocomplete-me ui-widget" id="myform" >
```

Comment: you did not define `e` as an argument. Try: `frm.submit(function (e) {`

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the form submitting, by passing an event to the function and preventing it:

```
var frm = $('#myform');
      frm.submit(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('#loader').show();
          $('#results-table').hide();
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
              type: frm.attr('method'),
              url: frm.attr('action'),
              data: frm.serialize(),
              async: true,
              success: function (data) {
                  $('#loader').hide();
                  $('#results-table').show();
                  $("#results-table").html(data);
              },

          });
          return false;
      });
```

`return false` won't do the trick.

Comment: Okay, that works for showing/hiding the display but now it just loads the entire page in the results table section not the data table.

Comment: So change the data that the ajax call is returning.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  can you explain further?  Wouldn't the data be coming from the form?

Comment: @jdv12, please post your `server-side` method.

Comment: When you make an ajax call, you send data (from the form) and it returns data. If you want different data, change your server-side code to return whatever data you want.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai, Why did you delete your comment?

Comment: I've been developing in django so my server side is handled by the view.  I'm just not sure I understand.  The ajax data property takes the results of the form and passes that to be rendered correct?  Which is what I'm trying to do so I'm not sure why its displaying the entire page in the results table section